# JasperReport: How to get date from the "oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP' field?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport 4.5.1 and i need to get the date from the **oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP**.
Inside the expression i tried with these two:

1. $F{DELIVERY_DATE}.dateValue()
2. $F{DELIVERY_DATE}.timestampValue()

but i am getting the same runtime error

**JasperReport Error:**

> Error filling print... Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : $F{DELIVERY_DATE}.dateValue()  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : $F{DELIVERY_DATE}.dateValue()      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:876) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:421) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:406) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:473) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:434) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:398) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:259) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247) 
>       at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:879) 
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP 
>       at Liste_colisage_par_rack_1439547941026_908820.evaluate(Liste_colisage_par_rack_1439547941026_908820:438) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:190) 
>       ... 19 more

Thanks in advance

Anand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

In iReport, JasperReport File's XML file :

```
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[*your query*]]>
</queryString>
    <field name="DELIVERY_DATE" class="oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Try changing it too

```
 <queryString>
        <![CDATA[*your query*]]>
</queryString>
    <field name="DELIVERY_DATE" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

You might be using the **DataType** `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` from Oracle Database to JasperReport directly when you are modifying **Report Query** in JasperReport.

i.e. Try changing `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` to `java.util.Date` in your jasperReport file and use the `DELIVERY_DATE Field` in Jasper Report directly

**NOTE:** 
You may have to repeatedly modify the dataType of DELIVERY_DATE to `java.util.Date` in XML of JasperReport if you modify the query in the Report Query section of JasperReport

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been addressed here http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514363/oraclesqltimestamp-javasqtimestamp

Answer (score 0):

for those that were led to this page searching for "oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP" search query - this might be occuring in other cases besides Jasper - for instance, for me, I was using my project on tomcat with ojdbc6.jar both loaded in my webapp, and in Tomcat /lib folder. The solution was to specify ojdbc6 library with "provided" scope in Maven dependencies of my webapp.

the root of the problem is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865917/classcastexception-because-of-classloaders)