# ClassCastException while call EJB over JNDI

Tags: ejb, weblogic, jndi, ear

I'm getting an ClassCastException while calling an EJB in an Pojo over JNDI. I use Oracle Weblogic Server 10.3.6 (EJB 3.0).

My structure:

- **app.ear**

  - lib

    - Interfaces.jar

      - MyBeanInterface.java
  - ejb.jar

    - MyBeanImpl.java
  - webapp.war

    - Client.java
    - WEB-INF

      - web.xml

My local Interface:

```
package mypackage;

@Local
public Interface MyBeanInterface {}
```

My EJB-Class:

```
package mypackage;

@Stateless(name = "MyBean")
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBeanInterface {}
```

My Client (not an EJB):

```
MyBeanInterface bean = (MyBeanInterface) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/MyBean");
```

My web.xml

```
 <ejb-local-ref>
   <ejb-ref-name>ejb/MyBean</ejb-ref-name>
   <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
   <local>mypackage.MyBeanInterface</local>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

My Exception:

The Lookup itself works. I get a reference. But when I want to cast with (MyBeanInterface) I get the following error:

Cannot cast an instance of "class mypackage.MyBeanInterface_whjkp6_MyBeanImpl (loaded by instance of weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader(id=28136))" to an instance of "interface mypackage.MyBeanInterface(loaded by instance of weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader(id=28144))

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the classes are loaded by different class loaders. Possible options are:

1) Ensure the classes are loaded by same class loader

2) Use reflection

3) Serialize and then deserialize

Refer:

1) [cast across classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591779/cast-across-classloader)

2) https://community.oracle.com/thread/757133

3) [ClassCastException because of classloaders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865917/classcastexception-because-of-classloaders)