# throwing exception while using innermost class of org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper

Tags: java, tomcat, oracle11g

`conn= Ds.getConnection();
Connection oraconn = ((DelegatingConnection)conn).getInnermostDelegate();`

its giving following exception
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection`

I have also set resource parameter `accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true`
need to unwrapp this object to pass to ArrayDescriptor
in server.xml of tomcat
please help thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection is a different class (different classloader) than the org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection from the connection.

this can be, if you are supplying this class via your container-bound warfile, and the connection is instantiated via tomcat (or other application server).

to test this you can use something like:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection").getClassLoader().toString()
conn.getClassLoader().toString();
```

you might be able ot use reflection. this from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591779/cast-across-classloader):

```
// 'source' is from another classloader
Method method = conn.getClass().getMethod("getInnermostDelegate", new Class[] {});
Object o = method.invoke(conn, new Object[] {});
```

However, i'm not sure the return argument is easily castable to a class in your current classloader.
If you follow the reflection method, make absolutely sure you encapsulate all of this in a single class, don't let things like Method and Object bleed out from this. I don't recommend this but it ought to work.

an alternative is to place your code in the same place as the connection. (tomcat lib)

ofcourse first check if indeed you are using 2 different classloaders for your code. :D

EDIT:

From the comments it looks like there are 2 classloaders at work here.
I forgot to mention a 3rd approach.

1. preferred: remove the jar file that supplies DelegatingConnection from your war file and rely on it being supplied by the common/lib classloader.
2. run your code in the common/lib classloader by placing the war there
3. reflect : probably bad, probably will give trouble casting the result object to the right class

Comment: I used this `Sysout("1)"+Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection").getClassLoader().toString());  
conn=ds.getConnection();
Sysout("2)"+conn.getClass().getClassLoader().toString());` OP  1)WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
StandardClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    file:D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\shared\classes\  -2) StandardClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    file:D:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\common\classes\

Comment: yeah that looks like 2 different classloaders to me. the first one is your container's classloader, the second one is it's parent, common/classes, which is shared by all war files.

Comment: you might fix it by not supplying the jar file / class file in WEB-INF/classes and only using the one already supplied in common/classes. If you can identify the specific jar file that you are supplying _and_ is present in the common/lib / common/classes  you could exclude it form your war file, hopefully

Comment: I removed commons-dbcp.1.2 jar from workspace lib ,but without importing  `org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection` class how can I use this   `Connection oraconn = ((DelegatingConnection)conn).getInnermostDelegate(); `

Comment: You should (probbaly) be able to still import it at runtime from the other classloader. keep your import statement in your code. you can also build against it, but just don't ship the jar file in your WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: I think it is not possible to import at runtime..giving error  `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The import org.apache.commons.dbcp cannot be resolved
 DelegatingConnection cannot be resolved to a type
`  thanx for your suggestions though

Comment: That is compile time, unless you are using a jsp. If you use the library to compile against (so when you generate classes it is there) but exclude it from packaging into the warfile (so in the warfile you put in tomcat, it isn't there), you should be able to run it. If you use maven in your project you can use <scope> provided</scope>

Comment: yes my project is 'jsp' servlet web app...and sorry but I didn't get your point

Comment: a jsp would (likely) be compiled by tomcat. If your code is being compiled from a jsp then the error you mentioned indicates you don't have access to the appropriate jar file. (though you are receiving runtime objects from it's governing classloader).    however the type of code you are writing is something I would normally only expect to be compiled and packaged into a warfile before being placed in tomcat. In that case, I would expect you compile against a set of jarfiles, and then create a distribution warfile in which you package any dependencies.

Comment: My point is that you use it during compilation but you remove it during packaging. (or for testing, delete it from the war/web-inf/lib after you have compiled).

Comment: how is it possible to do it every time...any way thanx for your reply

Comment: if you use maven, then marking the dependency as "provided" should mean it won't get packaged. If you use ant or make or batch script that packages, then you would need to use the specific tool.