# Cannot cast from child class to parent interface

Tags: java, class, plugins, casting

I am programming a plugin system for my Java Application. My problem is if I tryto cast from the Child Class to my Parent Interface
I get the ClassCastException `java.lang.ClassCastException: net.scrumplex.testplugin.Main cannot be cast to net.scrumplex.sprummlbot.plugins.SprummlPlugin`

My Interface:

```
package net.scrumplex.sprummlbot.plugins;

import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.BaseEvent;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.TS3EventType;

public interface SprummlPlugin {

    public boolean init(String version);

    public void end();

    public void handleEvent(TS3EventType type, BaseEvent event);

}
```

My TestPlugin:

```
package net.scrumplex.testplugin;

import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.BaseEvent;
import com.github.theholywaffle.teamspeak3.api.event.TS3EventType;

import net.scrumplex.sprummlbot.plugins.SprummlPlugin;

public class Main implements SprummlPlugin {

    @Override
    public void end() {
        System.out.println("Stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(TS3EventType type, BaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println(type.name());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean init(String arg0) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        return true;
    }

}
```

My PluginLoader:

```
public static void load(File jarFile) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException,
        IOException, PluginLoadException {
    String path = "";
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
    JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry("plugin.ini");
    InputStream input = jar.getInputStream(entry);
    Ini ini = new Ini(input);
    if (!ini.containsKey("Plugin")) {
        jar.close();
        throw new PluginLoadException("Ini file not compatible.");
    }
    Section sec = ini.get("Plugin");
    if (sec.containsKey("main")) {
        path = sec.get("main");
    }
    ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { jarFile.toURI().toURL() });
    SprummlPlugin plugin = (SprummlPlugin) loader.loadClass(path).newInstance();
    pluginslist.add(plugin);
    plugin.init(Vars.VERSION);
    jar.close();
}
```

The class path for the TestPlugin is correct

Comment: Is `SprummlPlugin` contained in your plugin's .jar?

Comment: no I exported that TestPlugin as Jar File not as a runnable jar file

Comment: Just make sure you have only one `SprummlPlugin` in the classpath at *any* time.

Comment: I only have my own SprummlPlugin. The Tst Plugin only implements it (I just added my Main Jarfile to the buildpath of the testplugin)

Comment: You are encountering a problem addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591779/cast-across-classloader)

Comment: You have two different classloaders: The `URLClassLoader` that you use for loading the class and the classloader of the current class. Therefore the class cannot be cast.

Comment: How could I fix this?

Comment: As per the second answer in the link I gave - you could use reflection.

Comment: Is there another way? I never worked with reflection. I am new in class loading and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I fixed this:

I added `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`to my `URLClassLoader.newInstance(...);`